# Colon Violation: Colons should be next to the identifier when specifying a type and next to the key in dictionary literals. (colon)

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I am currently using SwiftLint for the perfect coding standards in my projects. After installing it I am getting so many warnings and the common ones are:

> "Colon Violation: Colons should be next to the identifier when specifying a type and next to the key in dictionary literals. (colon)".

[image]

```
var indexPath:IndexPath!
static let collapsedHeigth : CGFloat = 80
static let expandedHeigth : CGFloat = 210
```

What does it means and how to improve it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The warning is telling you that your code should be:

```
static let collapsedHeigth: CGFloat = 80
static let expandedHeigth: CGFloat = 210
```

The colon should not have whitespace before it when declaring variables or when creating key-value pairs in a dictionary.

```
let someDictionary = [ "Hello": 4, "Bye": 42 ]
```

BTW - you can solve the "trailing whitespace" errors with a simple setting in Xcode preferences. Go to the Text Editing tab of the preferences and enable the "Automatically trim trailing whitespace" option.

Comment: How to change That rule